# Flutter Gesture Detection for Widget at the bottom of Stack

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to develop an interface similar to Google Maps using Flutter. My Flutter UI consists of a stack Widget, with the following child Widgets:

1. GoogleMaps (using the google maps plugin)
2. CustomScrollView with slivers (SliverPersistentHeader & SliverList)

I have made the SliverPersistentHeader be transparent so that the Google Maps shows below it. It looks fine, the only issue is GoogleMap could not get any gestures so it could not react to drag or tap gestures.

Any idea, how can I push the gestures down from the SliverHeader to GoogleMaps?

Here is a graphical representation of how the UI looks like.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think one solution would be to use the **IgnorePointer** widget as the parent of your SliverHeader, as it will make all its subtree invisible to hit testing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried IgnorePointer with the ignoring property, but it does not seem to have any effect. The Google Map widget under the SliverHeader remains un-response to gestures :(